# java.lang.NullPointerException in Selenium TestNG

Tags: java, selenium

I'm a one-week-newbie in learning both Selenium WebDriver and Java.

I tried to create a test script to run using TestNG.

I have 2 java files and 1 testng.xml as below:

[1] adminBase.java

```
package automation;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class adminBase {
static WebDriver driver;
public static String appURL = "https://00.0.00.00:0000/admin/";
public static String testData = "C:\src\TestData.xls";

//Declare fields on pageObject that are webElements
@FindBy(id = "j_username")
static WebElement username;
@CacheLookup

@FindBy(id = "j_password")
static WebElement password;
@CacheLookup

@FindBy(id = "login")
static WebElement loginBtn;

@FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='LogoutForm']/li/span/a")
static WebElement logoutBtn;


//This method will take two arguments (Username and Password)
public void loginInfo(String sUsername, String sPassword){
    username.sendKeys(sUsername);
    password.sendKeys(sPassword);
    loginBtn.click();
    }

//To read Excel file
public String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName) {
    String[][] arrayExcelData = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

        int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
        int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();

        arrayExcelData = new String[totalNoOfRows-1][totalNoOfCols];
        for (int i=1; i<totalNoOfRows; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<totalNoOfCols; j++){
                arrayExcelData[i-1][j] = sh.getCell(j, i).getContents();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (BiffException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayExcelData;
}
}
```

and also [2] adminLogin.java

```
package automation;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class adminLogin {
WebDriver driver;
adminBase adminbase;
String testData;

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeTest() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //adminbase = PageFactory.initElements(driver, adminBase.class);
}

@DataProvider(name="loginInfo")
public Object[][] getData() throws Exception {
    Object[][] user = adminbase.getExcelData(testData, "adminLogin");
    return user;
}

@Test(dataProvider="loginInfo")
public void test(String appURL, String sUsername, String sPassword)
throws Exception {
    driver.get(appURL);
    adminbase.loginInfo(sUsername, sPassword);
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterTest() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

[3] testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
  <classes>
    <class name = "automation.adminLogin"/>
  </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

however, i got below exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at automation.adminBase.getExcelData(adminBase.java:48)
    at automation.adminLogin.getData(adminLogin.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    ... 20 more
```

from what I understand there's error at line **automation.adminLogin.getData(adminLogin.java:27)**

line 27 in adminLogin.java file is this line:

```
(Object[][] user = adminbase.getExcelData(testData, "adminLogin");
```

I understand that the error might be due to I'm passing parameter with null. But i just don't know how to fix because i don't get any error in my files

My code really a mess. Because I just mix and match. 
I'm really sorry who get headache reading my code. >.<

Kindly comment and help for me to improve.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with `debugger`? The best way to find out this kind of issue is `debuger`

Comment: Hi @RuchiraGayanRanaweera
Could you advice me on how to use debugger?

Comment: Sure. what is the `IDE` you use for coding? Debugging option there.

Comment: Kindly share exception print stack trace.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera.. Eclipse IDE Mars Release 4.5.0 (is this what u mean)

Comment: @dieyb you can follow these steps to debug your code. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Also trying to analyze the stack trace of the error.. You can get the hint(line number) where will be the issue. Leave a comment if you are still confuse.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh,

I added the exception in above post. Kindly advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not setting the `adminbase` variable at any point in your AdminLogin class.

Just replace:

```
adminBase adminbase;
```

with:

```
adminBase adminbase = new adminBase();
```

if you just want an instance of the adminBase class.

Also by convention the class names are recommended to start with a capital letter. (i.e. AdminBase and AdminLogin)

**Note:**
This answer just addresses your immediate problem. Your code actually could do with some overall improvements. If you want others to review your code in detail and give you pointers on how you can improve your code, I would suggest you submit it on our [CodeReview site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hi @Ceiling Gecko,

Tried with your solution but i got new error. Basically the error is:


 `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at automation.adminBase.getExcelData(adminBase.java:48)
    at automation.adminLogin.getData(adminLogin.java:27)
    ... 20 more`

**Note:**
Thanks for your suggestion. Will do it. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You have exception at `FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);` in `getExcelData` method.

You are invoking `getExcelData` in `adminLogin` class as below:

```
Object[][] user = adminbase.getExcelData(testData, "adminLogin");
```

However `testData` is not initialized and so ultimately you are passing `null` to `FileInputStream`.

You have also declared `testData` in `adminBase` class. If you want use that then change code as below:

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(testData);
```